Predict future Implied Volatility Surface with LSV models
From my understanding, Local Stochastic Volatility (LSV) models (such as the Heston-LSV for instance) are ones of the most used diffusion models used for exotic pricing. One of their advantages (by comparison with Local Volatility models) stands in the fact that the forward volatility smile does not flatten as considered maturities increase.
My goal is to predict how the Implied Volatility Surface (IVS) changes with time. Indeed, the IVS derived from today's vanilla option prices is slightly different from the one we will derive tomorrow from quoted vanilla options.
My idea is to calibrate a LSV model to the current IVS and use it to price forward starting call and put options. From these forward starting option, I would then derive a "forward" implied volatility surface, and would use this forward IVS as an estimator of tomorrow's IVS.
This is quite a complicated idea, so I was wondering whether it had some chances to work before diving into all the maths and code. So here is my question: is using the LSV model for such a prediction purpose a valid idea? If so, how would I take advantage of past IVS to better calibrate my LSV model?
As a side question, if this is not the path you would have taken to predict the future whole IVS, what would you have done?
